# Cant save form data in data base -Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create a simple form which takes name and email as user input.
But after I submit,its not getting saved in database 
manage.py dumpdata shows [] i.e empty row.
Please help!

models.py

```
class EmpD(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

forms.py

```
class SubmitF(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField()
    email= forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = EmpD
        fileds = '_all_'
```

views.py

```
def submit_view(request):
template_name = 'emp/home.html'
redirect_url = 'emp/su.html'
form = SubmitF()

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SubmitF(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
       form.save()

       return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
else:
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})

def index(request):
return render(request, 'emp/home.html')
```

html containing form:

```
<form action='' method="post" >

{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}

<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<tr> <td style="width: 50%">
<label for="Name"><b>First name *</b></label><br />
<input name="Name" type="text" maxlength="50" style="width: 260px" />
</td> <td style="width: 50%">

</td> </tr> <tr> <td colspan="2">
<label for="Email_Address"><b>Email *</b></label><br />
<input name="Email_Address" type="text" maxlength="100" style="width: 535px" 
/>
</td> </tr> <tr> <td colspan="2">



<input  type="submit" value="Submit Data" />

</td> </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

app urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^$', views.submit_view, name='submit_view')]
```

Comment: please, fix indent in the views.py code and show your urls

Comment: (`fileds = '_all_'` --> `fields = '_all_'`)

Comment: @PRMoureu actually it's `fields = '__all__'` :)

Answer (score 0):

Modeling, separate form fields and 3 views for single form is very bad approach.
Try this. Define simple models.For Email Input, define Email Field, form itself do its validation.

Models.py

```
class EmpD(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Define forms.py, if you want to include models fields, just `fields='__all__'` will do it for you, 
otherwise define other fields in this form

forms.py

```
class SubmitF(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmpD
        fields = '__all__'
```

Simple views.py, if request method is Get, form renders and In Post request, data passed to server.

```
def submit_view(request):
    template_name = 'path_to_html'
    redirect_url = 'your_url'
    form = SubmitF()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SubmitF(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
    else:
        return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
```

Template Structure

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    <label for="name">Your name: </label>
    <input id="id_name" type="text" name="name" value="{{ current_name }}">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Comment: why you add `login_required` ?

Comment: remove it, no matter :)

Comment: i mean you can create new troubles for OP and it is  absent  in the current logic

Comment: @Sagar I tried your simple way and made all the changes,but dumpdata still shows empty row

Comment: @Sagar Do I need to create url pattern for  submit_view defined in views.py?

Comment: @Sagar OK done that..see the updated views.py and urls.py .its still not working